# Choosing random cards from a deck?

Tags: random

Is there a difference between the 2 below methods for choosing a random card from a deck of cards?  Is one approach more accepted than the other?

Method 1:  Generate a random number from 1-52 for the first card them remove that card from the array and choose a number from 1-51, then 1-50, then 1-49, etc... to get subsequent cards from the deck.

Method 2:  Generate a number from 1-52 and add that number to a “used numbers array”.  For each additional card, continue to choose a number from 1-52 each time, then check the used numbers array to see if it’s already been used.  Repeat generating a number between 1-52 until you get a result that hasn’t been used, then add it to the used number array.

Obviously, method 1 is more efficient in terms of compute cycles - but is there any other difference between the 2 approaches?  Is one approach “more random” than the other?  Or “better” for any other reason related to the quality of the randomization?

Comment: *"is there any other difference between the 2 approaches?"* - no, there is not. *"Is one approach “more random” than the other?"*  - no. To prove this, think about the probabilities of choosing the next number to pick from the deck.

Comment: Better: use Fisher-Yates to shuffle the deck in place, then just draw cards. Requires only one random number per card and no extra storage. Linear time.

Comment: Also Method 2 takes expected n log n time (for n the size of the deck) and Method 1 takes quadratic time if you actually remove.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I’m curious though as to what I did wrong here to receive so many negative notes...did I break some sort of rule?

Comment: @Jim, I would guess that the down-votes and close-votes are because this isn't exactly on topic; this seems to be a better fit for either mathematics or for computer science. IIRC your two processes are, in fact, equivalent as far as the randomness is concerned. There isn't a 'more random' but you can be less than random, i.e. your process could leak information or be predictable to some extent that someone could have a better than random chance at guessing the order, next card, etc.

Comment: @AlexReinking Are you sure you have the correct calculation for O()? Method 2 is unbounded in the worst case! Method 1 runs in O(n) when counting the number of loops, also method1's loop body can be written to run in constant time! so O(n)*O(1) is still O(n); n.b. removing the number from the array can be completed using a single swap with the chosen number and the end of the array, then the array is simply truncated the loop body will run in constant time. Method2's loop body depends length of the 'used' array each iteration cost between 1 and infinity loops!

Comment: @esoterik - Method 1 is O(n) when you implement via swapping. By "actually remove", I meant the usual array removal, which preserves the order. For Method 2, I explicitly gave _expected_ time. To see this: in iteration k, you have a probability (n-k)/n of hitting a good number, so it will take you n/(n-k) tries to hit in expectation. There are n rounds, so this is `sum from 0 .. n-1 of n/(n-k)` which is the same as `n * Hn` where Hn is the nth harmonic number, which grows as O(log n). Overall, that's O(n log n)

Comment: @esoterik  Thanks for the explanation. I wasn’t aware that there was a math version of StackExchange. I’m writing a Bingo app and wanted to make sure that my code was able to stand up to scrutiny regarding its “randomness”. The difference between a game of cards and Bingo is that cards are shuffled once before the hand starts but in Bingo, the numbers are being constantly shuffled. I do understand that in principle my 2nd method could run almost infinitely - but with the range 1-75, is it really something to worry about? (just asking out of curiosity) I’ll use the first, more efficient method.

Answer (score 2):

Completely depends on the pseudo-random number sequence.

Lets assume a good RNG that generates K bits per call with each bit being statistically random, an independent probability of 50%.

**Picking from the remaining cards**

In the first example you are using every number generated from the RNG sequence. You are calling the RNG 51 times, given that the last card picks itself.

However most numbers between 2 and 52 are not even powers of 2. As such you cannot in a statically unbiased way generate numbers in the ranges from 1 to 52 (or 0 to 51 same issues). There will always be a slightly higher chance that some index will be chosen first.

**Dead Numbers**

In the second example you are introducing dead numbers. By discarding any number that is not 1-52 or has already been drawn each card will have a statistically equal chance of being anywhere in the sort.

The problem with the second solution is that:

1. the RNGs are not guaranteed to generate every number atleast once - hence it may never terminate.
2. the algorithm has an unknown runtime - because the last required number may be at position 2^64 of the RNG and each intermediate position must be generated first.

**Swapping places**

A better algorithm would be to shuffle the cards, by swapping two random locations in the deck some high number of times. see [Fisher-Yates Shuffling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

The benefit here is that shuffling has a bounded time, and the quality of the shuffle is less dependent on the quality of the RNG then the two previous methods.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and advice.  My use case is actually for Bingo Balls in a drum and not a deck of cards.  I thought the scenarios were similar enough that any answer I received would apply to both scenarios - but I see the difference now would be that with a deck of cards, you set the order at the beginning (by shuffling) but for Bingo balls, the uncalled numbers would continue to bounce around until called.  I’m not sure I understand what you mean by dead numbers.  How is it possible for a number to never be selected?

Comment: A Dead Number in this case is a number that when drawn, does nothing. Either because it was never drawable (52<x like 53) or it has already been drawn ie: 1, 51, 3, 51. That last 51 had already been drawn hence is dead. As for the similarity from the perspective of probability there is no difference. The cage is simply a device that emits a sequence of balls. A deck of cards emits a sequence of cards. Each ball/card occurs once in the entire sequence and both sequences are finite. Your goal is presumably to randomly select one of these permuted sequences and reveal it element by element.